# How to use SSL for an express.js/node.js rest api?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

as I've looked around I haven't found much information regarding this:
What is the most-common (best practice) way to secure a rest-api build with mongo, express and node with SSL?

Any point in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What links did you read? Maybe this is a [good starting point](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-encryption). If you use Atlas communication with driver that's already encrypted; and the data in the hard drive is also encrypted. Another good resource is the [tutorial on SSL by mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Comment: In short, there are 3 levels of encryption standard 1. "wire encryption" (eavesdroppers on the network), 2. database encryption (on the storage), and 3. field level (apparently on the driver, this is quite new). If you use Atlas which is recommended to beginners, 1 & 2 are done for you, 3 can be enabled (not sure if this is possible on free tier).